# Scrolling an Iframe (cross domain) - faking the div to scroll

Tags: jquery, css, html, iframe

I have been reading about that Javascript cannot be used directly on iframe if it is from another domain because it violates the cross domain security. I read about a solution on to wrap the iframe inside a div tag and make the div tag scrollable.
What I am trying to achieve - 
Load the iframe from another domain as a whole page and auto scroll it down.

```
<div id="row_frame">
<iframe id="frame1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#frame1{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
border: none;   
}

#row_frame{
top:0px;
left:0px;
height: 100%;
width:100%;
background-color:Gray;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

So far I have come up with this to display the iframe inside the div. How would I use the javascript to scroll the div now? 
Can the jquery scrollto() with animation be used on the div?

Comment: To `scroll` the `div`? or `scroll` TO the `div`? Scrolling the `div` will require a fixed `height` with `overflow: auto;` property or `overflow-y` to be precise

Comment: @Mr.Alien It seems he is looking to scroll the div, not scroll to it

Comment: I cannot scroll the frame using jquery, so I have to be able to scroll the div

Comment: Alright I was able to achieve this by giving frame height a high value and making div {overflow:hidden}. This way I am scrolling div. But now my iframe has src that loads dynamically as page reaches bottom, which wont be reflected on my site since scrolling is on div.